# Cannot commit Android Studio Project to Bitbucket - "Home Variable is Not defined"

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket, git-commit

I'm trying to commit a project to Bitbucket and I'm getting this error:
[image: Error Message]

Anyone knows, what I should do?

Comment: Which operating system are you running on your computer?

Comment: i'm running windows 8.1

Comment: I fixed it, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I am pretty sure that your Android Studio is not able to find your local installation of git.

I would also encourage you to try and Commit from the shell to see if my last affirmation is true.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It's not even working from the shell.

Comment: Make sure that you installed git properly, do you have any info that you could provide in order to help you

Comment: I fixed it by reinstalling everything. Weird. Thanks again.